# have publish_actions approved but facebook post not public

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My android application have publish_actions submission were approved but when I post photo on facebook via my application It's not public post because my friend on facebook cannot see this that post.

```js
final String hashTagPost = hashtag;
                callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions"); //I added publish_actions
                loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
                loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);
                loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                                .setBitmap(bitmap)
                                .setCaption(txtCaption.getText().toString() + " #EventPocket " + hashTagPost)
                                .build();
                        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                                .addPhoto(photo)
                                .build();
                        ShareApi.share(content, null);

                        Toast.makeText(PhotoActivity.this, "Post Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                    }
                }
```

This a part of my application.
What I do it more?

Comment: Did you log your code to check if actually you're sending anything?

Comment: I use facebook SDK v.4.6
In my post have public privacy but this post can see only me.

Comment: Did you set your app public in app dashboard?

Comment: Oops!! I forget to add contact email and set general public because my app is beta app.

Thank you  ^U^